# how can remove systemd and use upstart in ubuntu 16

Tags: ubuntu, systemd, upstart

I try to remove systemd service and install upstart in Ubuntu 16.4 but when remove and reboot it, system won't boot, just purple screen. 
how can remove or disable systemd ?

Comment: AFAIK, Ubuntu goes to systemd more and more. So maybe try to use another distro? But if this is what you want - [see here if this will help you](http://askubuntu.com/questions/779640/how-to-remove-systemd-from-ubuntu-16-04-and-prevent-its-usage)